# Add php.ini to SCA Fortify

Tags: php, fortify

I have a series of errors when scanning my project with Fortify:

[warning]: The PHP frontend was unable to resolve the following includes: Mail.php at main.php:174.
[warning]: It may be helpful to pass your php.ini file to SCA, so the include_path directive can be examined.
[warning]: Unexpected exception while parsing file (javascript) index.php: Parse error at line 2, column 17.  Encountered: _ffy_tag

I tried adding my PATH to the PEAR directory in the "Environmental Variables" for Windows. But still would error.

Not to sure how to do this "It may be helpful to pass your php.ini file to SCA, so the include_path directive can be examined." . I tried starting a scan wizard and including the php.ini file in the scan but it would still produce the error.

I included the full path within the code and the error switched to "
[warning]: The PHP frontend was unable to resolve the following includes:
        PEAR.php at RFC822.php:198."

So really my question is how do I "pass my php.ini file to SCA"? Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks,

Tom

Just a sidenote my php.ini include_path does have the my directory included.

Comment: The include_path is defined in the php.ini file
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Comment: My php.ini file already includes the path to the pear directory where my Mail.php class exists.

Answer (score -1):

Tom using this will include php.ini in you scan. My example is based off having zend server community installed on a Unix/Linux system.

sourceanalyzer -b mybuild . /usr/local/zend/etc/php.ini

When you look at your auditworkbench it will also include suggested changes to the ini file.